# Do I really have to set a url in angular-ui when making states?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

When i code the states using

```
$stateProvider.state('test.state', { templateUrl: 'my-template.html' });
```

It still successfully changes to a different state even if I did not specify the url.

It got me thinking that if I wanted an easy way to prevent people from accessing certain url's that I would just leave the url blank.

Is there a downside I am not seeing to leaving the url blank?

Comment: Yes, you cannot pass the url's to someone to checkout the page. The url's are more for the users (user friendly)

Comment: It would be quite easy to navigate to your state via the console